# Is it possible to work in Malta with a spouse/family reunification residence-permit?

Tags: visa, working-visas, resident-permit, work-permit, malta

I am a non-EU national. I have a query that if it is possible to work in Malta with a spouse/family reunification residence-permit.

Thank you.